# Escape `$` in regex pattern matching in Terraform

Tags: terraform

How shall I escape the dollar sign `$` in Terraform pattern matching? Based on the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regex) I thought `\$` would do:

```
[ for spn in group.new_spn_owners : spn if length(regexall("^\$.*", spn)) == 0 ]
```

but I'm getting:

```
The symbol "$" is not a valid escape sequence selector.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HCL2 you must double escape special characters in regular expression objects:

```
regexall("^\\$.*", spn)
```

This is also true for relevant sequences e.g. `\\d` instead of `\d`.